# How to use jQuery syntax as string to set as Title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use `$("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod();` as string to set as title to the webpage ?

I'm trying to use as below but see the error as **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"**

```
var myString = "$("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod()";
document.title = myString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code

```
var myString = "$('#mycustomtext').CustomMethod()";
document.title = myString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape strings,

```
var myString = "$(\"#mycustomtext\").CustomMethod()";
                 ^^^            ^^^
document.title = myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `document.title = "My Webpage"`.
In your case, it should be,

```
var myString = '$("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod()'
document.title = myString
```

Remember to escape the quotes or use alternating single and double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You're adding an extra set of quotation marks. Don't wrap the function in quotes.

```
var myString = $("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod();
document.title = myString;
```

If you do want this functionality, though, you will need to escape the inner quotes: `"$(\"#mycustomtext\").CustomMethod()";`

Answer (score -2):

You have an unexpected quote mark in your script. It should be like this

```
var x = 
var myString = $("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod();
document.title = myString;
```

I removed quotes in the start and end because it's read as a string and your real title will not be the result of the expression **$("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod()** but the title will be exactly **$("#mycustomtext").CustomMethod()**